# Finding digits (in a number) that exactly divide the number

Tags: c++, int, modulus, digits

I am writing a program to find the number of digits in a number that exactly divide that number (remainder=0).

For example, for 145. There are 2 digits that divide 145, 1 and 5(145%2=0,145%1=0).

When a number contains a 0 as a digit, like 102, the program fails. I understand that I can't divide by zero, i tried to solve this, but the program is still not working. Any suggestions on how to avoid division by zero?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
std::cout<<"Enter a number: ";
int n,digit,count=0;
std::cin>>n;

    while(n){
        digit = n%10;
        if(digit==0) continue;
        else{
            if(n%(digit)==0) count++; n /= 10;}
    }

std::cout<<"Number of digits that divide the number: "<<count<<"\n"; count=0;
}
```

Comment: What should be the result for `333`, one (because only `3` divides the number) or three (because there are three `3`s in the number)?

Comment: Move `n /= 10;` statement to immediately after calculating digit = n%10;.

Comment: *"The program is not working"* is not very specific. I understood what you meant, but you should make a habit of being explicit. And another hint: debug your code by printing some checkpoints and variables. Understand your flow.

Comment: @user1990169 if I move n/= 10 to immediately after caculating digit=n%10. The answer(count) will be wrong, because n%(digit) will use updated value.

Comment: If `digit` is ever zero, you get stuck in an endless loop, because in that case you are forgetting to divide `n` by `10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int n , digit, count = 0;
    std::cin >> n;
    int cn = n;

    while (n){

        digit = n % 10;
        n /= 10;

        if (digit == 0) continue;
        else{
            if (cn % (digit) == 0) count++;             
        }

    }
```